# Handling MultipartFile with @RequestBody in Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, file-upload

Scenario: Upload file(s) in angular with some other data and capturing them in REST controller. 
My model in angular is as follows.

```
export class MetaData{
  files: FormData;
  docTypeId: number;
  metadata: any;
  employeeID: number;
}
```

Now I want to make a POST to my REST endpoint and capture the details as follows.

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public StatusDTO uploadDocument(@RequestBody MetaDataDTO metadata){
}
```

My MetaDataDTO class as follows - (1)

```
public class MetaDataDTO {
    private List<MultipartFile> files;
    private Integer docTypeId;
    private List<Map<String, String>> metaData;
    private Integer employeeID;
}
```

But this endpoint is not called by angular service.
p.s. I can modify my REST endpoint as follows.

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
        public StatusDTO uploadDocument(@RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> files, @RequestParam("metaData") String rawMetaData){
// from GSON convert rawMetaData to MetaDataDTO class. 
}
```

Now my modified MetaDataDTO - (2) as follows.

```
public class MetaDataDTO {
 private Integer docTypeId;
 private List<Map<String, String>> metaData;
 private Integer employeeID;
}
```

But now I miss my mapping which is define in MetaDataDTO -(1) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with submitting base64 array for a file than converting the file with formdata.